# how to add buttons on the panel in android app?

Tags: android, user-interface

how to add these buttons on the panel?

[image]

Comment: The "panel" is what is known in Android as [the action bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). The documentation has [a section on adding action items](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems), where "action items" are "these buttons".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the action bar that you are trying to add buttons to.

Please take a look at the official documentation:
[Check the Add action Items paragraph](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)